# Initial value of state in useReducer not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, jsx

I have problem when I initiate state in `useReducer` using localStorage

AuthContext.jsx

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react"
import jwt from "jwt-decode"

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {    
  switch(action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return {
        user: action.payload
      }
    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {    
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, { user: null });

  useEffect(() => {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

    if (refreshToken) {
      const decodedJwt = jwt(refreshToken);
         
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGIN",
        payload: {
          nama: decodedJwt.nama,
          role: decodedJwt.role
        }
      })
    }
  }, []);

  console.log('AuthContext state: ', state);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{...state, dispatch}}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Index from './pages/Index.jsx'
import Login from "./pages/auth/Login.jsx"
import { useAuthContext } from './hooks/useAuthContext.js'

const App = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthContext();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path='/'
          element={user ? <Index /> : <Navigate to='/login' />}
        />
        <Route
          path='/login'
          element={<Login/>}
        />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default App
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { AuthContextProvider } from './context/AuthContext.jsx'
import App from './App.jsx'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  // <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthContextProvider>
      <App/>
    </AuthContextProvider>
  // </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

So, when I go to page `"/"` with not empty localStorage, the page always redirect to `"/login"`. The initial value it's not actually initiated before render component.

I have a screenshot for this

[image]

The initial state always return null at first.

Comment: `useEffect` runs after component renders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
>   authReducer,
>   { user: null }
> );
> ```

You've passed `{ user: null }` as the initial value, so the log is correct. The `useEffect` hook runs as the end of the render cycle and enqueues a state update which triggers a component rerender and then the updated state is logged.

I'm guessing that you are troubleshooting why the UI is redirecting to `"/login"` when the app mounts/loads when the user is "authenticated". This happens because the "unauthenticated" user condition matches the initial "I don't know the auth status yet" condition, e.g. they are both `null`, and so the UI incorrectly redirects prematurely.

You could address this by using a *different* initial value that doesn't mask the "unauthenticated" state.

Example:

```
export const authReducer = (state, action) => {    
  switch(action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return {
        user: action.payload
      };

    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialState = {
  user: undefined, // <-- initially undefined
};
```

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {    
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

    if (refreshToken) {
      const decodedJwt = jwt(refreshToken);
         
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGIN",
        payload: decodedJwt // <-- confirmed authenticated. 
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: "LOGIN",
        payload: null       // <-- confirmed unauthenticated
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Check for the "unknown auth" condition and ***don't*** render the redirect or protected content yet.

```
const App = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthContext();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path='/'
          element={user === undefined
            ? null // <-- or loading spinner/indicator/etc
            : user ? <Index /> : <Navigate to='/login' replace />
          }
        />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

### Improvement Suggestion

You might also be able to avoid the "initial render issue" by passing a third argument to the `useReducer` hook to initialize the state. The initializer will be called and compute the initial state value that will be available to the component for the initial render cycle.

Example:

```
export const authReducer = (state, action) => {    
  switch(action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return {
        user: action.payload
      };

    case "LOGOUT":
      return {
        user: null
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const initialState = {
  user: null,
};

const initializer = () => {
  const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

  return refreshToken ? jwt(refreshToken) : initialState;
};
```

```
export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {    
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, null, initializer);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code working fine,Just console log after bit delay

```
setTimeOut(()={
console.log('AuthContext state: ', state);
},500)
```